# 404 on existing file in codeigniter and nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have setup codeigniter in a sub-folder with nginx server.

I have multiple codeigniter installation in the nginx, like:

```
www.example.com/test

www.example.com/test1
```

I have one folder in test directory sitemap. When I am accessing `www.example.com/test/sitemap/sitemap.xml.gz` its giving me 404 error.

My nginx file is

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen[::]: 80;

  root / usr / share / nginx / html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  server_name www.example.com;

  access_log /
    var / log / nginx / access.log;
  error_log /
    var / log / nginx / error.log error;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri / = 404;
  }

  location / test {
    root / usr / share / nginx / html / test;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri / /test/index.php;
    location~ * ^ /(assets|files|robots\.txt) { }
  }

  location / test2 {
    root / usr / share / nginx / html / test2;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri / /test2/index.php;

  }
  error_page 404 / 404. html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 / 50 x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
  root / usr / share / nginx / html;
}

location~ * \.(ico | css | js | gif | jpe ? g | png | svg | woff2 | woff | ttf) $ {
  expires max;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache - Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

location~ * ^ /(assets|files|robots\.txt) { }
location~/\.ht {
deny all;
}

location~\.php$ {
  try_files $uri = 404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^ (. + \.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run / php5 - fpm.sock; fastcgi_index index.php; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Didn't used htaccess as I am using Nginx server

Comment: `www.example.com/index.php/test` try once like this..

Comment: my codeigniter is resied in test folder. I tried www.example.com/test/index.php/sitemap/sitemap.xml.gz but not luck same 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your per-location `root` directives are probably unnecessary and incorrect.

The document root is generally inherited from the surrounding `server` block, and only needs to be specified inside a `location` block if it changes for that context.

If your URI `/test/index.php` is located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.php`, then the correct value for `root` is `/usr/share/nginx/html`, irrespective of whether it appears in the `server` block or `location` block.

Your are currently specifying paths like: `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/test/index.php` and `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/test/sitemap/sitemap.xml.gz`.

You should remove the `root` statements from the `location` blocks, as the correct value has already been specified above, in your `server` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.